# Ajax Sqlite could not find driver./SQLSTATE[HY000]

Tags: php, ajax, sqlite

i am trying to realize an exercice with Ajax and Sqlite database for which i use DB Browser for SQLite. The purpose of the exercice is to have two combobox fill each other in cascade. But first of all i need to fill the first one from data that i gather from the Database. But i am blocked on that first step.

Here is the code i made until now :

```
<?php
try
{
$db = new 
PDO('sqlite3:\C:\xampp\htdocs\www\TPLigueDesChampions\ligueChampions.db');
$result = $db->query('SELECT pays FROM listepays');
echo ' <select name=\'Code\'><br>';
echo ' <option value=\'0\'>Choisissez</option>';
 foreach($result as $row)
{
echo '<option value=\''.$row['Pays'].'<option><br>';
//echo "hello";
}
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
print 'Exception : '.$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

So when i make sqlite3 in pdo call i have the following error:
"Could not find driver"
And when i use sqlite normal it gives me out this: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file

I searched in internet about a solution but everything i found until now is related to MySQL and i need SQLite. Can you please help?

Comment: do you need change this function to ajax function ??

Answer (score 0):

**for php**

```
<?php
$bd = new SQLite3('ligueChampions.db');

$results = $bd->query('SELECT pays FROM listepays');
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
    var_dump($row);
}
?>
```

[SQLite3 and Php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php)

Comment: First of all thank you so much @Tegito123 , but just minutes after i posted this i changed it to $bd = new SQLite('.ligueChampions.db'); and it doesnt show the error anymore , however it is not full i guess i am mistaken on the query now